# Is the probability density function of a random variable unique?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In many definitions involving the cumulative distribution function, the article "the" is used for the probability density function :

e.g:
"the function $f_{X,Y}$" is called $\bf{the}$ joint probability density function of the random vector $\bf{X}$ $=(X,Y)$

Is the probability density of function of a random variable unique?

Answer (score 5):

It is unique up to set a of measure $0$. It is customary to say 'the' density function with the understanding that two functions are treated as  equal when they are equal except on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be of measure 0?

Comment: ignore the measure 0 bit if you dont understand it